# Modify HTTP response header with (Client-side) Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http

I'm working on a website, and I've run into trouble modifying an HTTP Response header using (client-side) JavaScript. I have exactly zero idea how to do this. I know (roughly) how to make the 'for' loop to modify the header, but I don't know how to access the header within the script. Could y'all fine people help me with this *fun* task?

Comment: mind if I ask what you're trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: But I think this has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Javascript doesn't process the response until after the headers have been received.

Comment: JavaScript is the wrong layer (typically) to set HTTP Response headers... Are you using node.js or something?

Comment: @Barmar: Depends on where the JavaScript is running. If it's running on the server...

Comment: It would make sense if he was doing this via AJAX, correct? Wouldn't necessarily have to be node.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unless they specifically say they're using something like Node.js, I'm going to regularly assume that JS == client, not server.

Comment: Alright, for clarification: I need to modify the response header to remove X-Frame-Options to load one site in an iFrame. Is it possible to have the script run after receipt of the header, then pass the header along to the iFrame afterwards?

Comment: Also, @scunliffe I'm using clientside JS

Comment: No, you can't override X-Frame-Options with JS, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @crashcheetos you're not going to be able to remove headers that were already sent (especially if the site that sent them isn't yours).

Answer (score 8):

With *client-side* JavaScript (JavaScript running in a browser), you can't do this; by the time the JavaScript code runs, the headers have already been processed.

Comment: Hey T.J., I'll defer to your experience, but generally I'd comment on an answer like this that it is better suited as a comment, as it really just asks for clarification...

Comment: @ZachL: I was 99% sure the OP meant client-side. That 1% is why I went with CW. :-) (Well, that and there were at least three comments saying "You can't do this with client-side JavaScript..." :-) ) Making it an *answer* means that if I was right about the OP meaning client-side, it's something they can accept. (You can't "accept" a comment.)

Comment: ahhh.. didn't notice the CW tag. Thanks for clarifying. Hope you don't mind I went ahead and removed the "server-side" part from your answer after editting "client-side" into the question.

Comment: If I were to implement the proper code server-side, then what code would I need / where the hell would I put this in terms of site directory?